# getting day from string timestamp

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with keys which are time-stamps in string format ("2016-01-02"). Im trying to convert these keys into the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday etc..) based on name preferably and not the numbers 0-6. I've been trying to do it using different versions of the code below which I found on SE, but am having trouble. Ive been getting different errors like it doesn't take strings but when ive tried to do it with ints it doesn't work either, can anyone give a hand

```
for key, value in adict.iteritems():
    key = key.date()
    calendar.day_name[key.weekday()]
```

This isn't the exact code im using ive just been doing all sorts of stuff with this main code to try to get it to work.

Comment: This is rather unclear. What is is `adict`?  what is `calendar`? Um?

Comment: format that question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module for that and [`strptime()`/`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) facilities to do your bidding:

```
import datetime

for key in adict:
    day = datetime.datetime.strptime(key, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%A")
    print(day)
```

Beware, tho, that day names have lower entropy than actual dates so if you're trying to *rename* the keys you'll most likely end up overwriting some of your data.